# Troubleshooting Box Rendering in CropModal

Tags: reactjs

```
// TopMenu.jsx

import styles from "./TopMenu.module.css";
import CropModal from "../CropModal";

const TopMenu = memo(
  () => {
    const [croppable, setCroppable] = useState(false);

    const handleCropClick = () => {
      setCroppable(true);
    };

    const handleCustomCrop = (width, height) => {
      setCropDimensions({ width, height });
      setCroppable(true);
    };


    return (
        <Button onClick={handleCropClick}>Crop</Button>
        {croppable && (
          <CropModal
            visible={croppable}
            onCancel={() => setCroppable(false)}
            onConfirm={(width, height) => handleCustomCrop(width, height)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default TopMenu;
```

```
// CropModal.jsx

import { Button, Input, Modal } from "antd";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { showSwal } from "../util/util";

const CropModal = ({ visible, onCancel, onConfirm }) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const [isBoxRendered, setIsBoxRendered] = useState(false); // isBoxRendered를 true로 초기화

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    if (width && height) {
      onConfirm(Number(width), Number(height));
      console.log(width, height);
      setIsBoxRendered(true);
      onCancel();
    } else {
      showSwal({
        title: "Invalid dimensions",
        text: "Please enter valid width and height.",
        icon: "error"
      });
    }
  };

  const handleWidthChange = (event) => setWidth(event.target.value);
  const handleHeightChange = (event) => setHeight(event.target.value);

  return (
    <Modal
      title="Crop"
      open={visible}
      onCancel={onCancel}
      footer={[
        <Button key="cancel" onClick={onCancel}>
          Cancel
        </Button>,
        <Button key="confirm" type="primary" onClick={handleConfirm}>
          Confirm
        </Button>
      ]}
    >
      <Input placeholder="Width" value={width} onChange={handleWidthChange} type="number" />
      <Input placeholder="Height" value={height} onChange={handleHeightChange} type="number" />

      {isBoxRendered && (
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            width: Number(width),
            height: Number(height),
            border: "2px solid black"
          }}
        >
        </div>
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default CropModal;
```

When I click the Crop button, a modal window appears where I can enter the width and height, and when I click the Confirm button after entering the width and height, I want to draw a box that reflects the width and height,

Currently there is an issue where the value of isBoxRendered always comes out as false even though I set it to setIsBoxRendered(true) inside the handleConfirm function inside the CropModal.jsx file. I would like to know what part of my code is wrong.